# Adjective-position in movies titles

Tags: adjectives, adjective-position

Why is it "Mission Impossible" not "Impossible Mission" and so in "The Lion King", why not "The King Lion", and so on? I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: It’s actually “Mission: Impossible” with a colon.

Comment: Ah! I didn't notice that before. Thanks anyway! But what about "The Lion King"? Does it mean "the king of the lions" or "the king that is a lion"?

Comment: the king that is a lion.

Comment: Remember that the lion king is actually king of the jungle, all the animals are his subjects.

Comment: Note that neither "lion" nor "king" are adjectives, they're both nouns.

Comment: A related question: [*What is the position of nouns that work as adjectives?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/274781/407392)

Answer (score 3):

English has a fair amount of flexibility when it comes to the ordering of nouns and their adjectives.  Reversing the usual order often makes a movie title seem more exotic and interesting without compromising its comprehensibility.  This occasionally leads to ambiguity -- is "fish sauce" a sauce *for* fish, or a sauce *made out of* fish, or both?

Other examples include:  [The Life Aquatic with Steve Zissou](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0362270/) ...okay that's all I can think of right now, but I trust more will appear in comments.

Comment: Exotic, interesting, or poetic; see also [Noun-adjective reversal - was it ever in use in plain speech?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161298/noun-adjective-reversal-was-it-ever-in-use-in-plain-speech) Another example is the 1931 stage play _The House Beautiful_, which Dorothy Parker famously described in print as "the play lousy."